# How to prove that space is not connected

Tags: general-topology

I found a definition that the space $M$ is not connected if there are open subsets $A,B$ such that $M=A\cup M,A\ne\emptyset\ne B,$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$. How can I prove from the definition that $[0, 10) \cup (10, 20]$ is not a connected subset of $\mathbb R$? Is it just by choosing $A=[0,10),B=(10,20]$ or are those open?

Comment: yeah you are right...they are open in the sense of sub-space topology

Comment: There are another equivalent definition with separated sets..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A space $X$ is said to be *connected* if whenever $U$ and $V$ are two nonempty open sets such that $U\cup V = X$, then $U\cap V\neq\varnothing$. In other words, a space is not connected if you can find two nonempty open subsets $U,V$ of $X$ such that $U\cap V =X$ and $U\cap V = \varnothing$. If you can, then $U$ and $V$ are called a *separation* of $X$.

Now, let $[0,10)\cup(10,20]=X$. Your sets $A$ and $B$ are open in the subspace topology since 
$$A = (-\infty,10)\cap X\quad\text{and}\quad B = (10,\infty)\cap X.$$
You should be able to conclude from here.